# Split panel into subpanels

Tags: split, panel, stata

I have a panel data set in Stata, which has industry and year dimensions and 7 other variables. I want to split this panel into subpanels by industry-year combination and then use them to calculate new variables using the  `mahascore` from `mahapick.ado` package. 
Here is the structure of data sample (numbers for varlist are not real, in my data set they are just some numerical variables):

```
firm_id  year  ind_id     var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var 7
1        2008     1         1    2   3    4    5     6   7
1        2009     1         1    2   3    4    5     6   7
1        2010     1         1    2   3    4    5     6   7
.................................................................   
2        2008     2000      1    2   3    4    5     6   7
2        2009     2000      1    2   3    4    5     6   7
2        2010     2000      1    2   3    4    5     6   7
...............................................................
```

For each of these variables I want to generate 72 new variables (9 industries * 8 years), so that all values for each variable that does not belong to industry-year combination are missing. Than I want to generate 72 varlists, which I will use to calculate `mahascore` (Mahalanobis distance) separately for each industry-year combination. The industry ids (ind_ids) take following values {1 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000}. The time period spans from 2008 to 2015.

The code that I wrote is wrong but I hope it will help to understand what I am doing:

```
*Generate 504 variables(8 years*9 industries * 7variables):

forvalues i = 2008/2015 {
  forvalues z = 1/9000 {
       gen var1_`i'_`z'=var1 if year == `i' & ind_id == `z'
       gen var2_`i'_`z'=var2 if year == `i' & ind_id == `z'
       gen var3_`i'_`z'=var3 if year == `i' & ind_id == `z'
       gen var4_`i'_`z'=var4 if year == `i' & ind_id == `z'
       gen var5_`i'_`z'=var5 if year == `i' & ind_id == `z'
       gen var6_`i'_`z'=var6 if year == `i' & ind_id == `z'
       gen var7_`i'_`z'=var7 if year == `i' & ind_id == `z'
 }
 }
 *Create 72 varlists (with 7 variables for each year-industry combination):  
  global varlist1 var1_2008_1 var2_2008_1 var3_2008_1 var4_2008_1 var5_2008_1 var6_2008_1 var7_2008_1
   global varlist2 var1_2009_1 var2_2009_1 var3_2009_1 var4_2009_1 var5_2009_1 var6_2009_1 var7_2009_1
 ....................................................................
 *Create list of lists     
 global metavarlist varlist1 varlist2...varlist72
 *Calculate distance
       foreach v in  $metavarlist {
          mahascore `v', gen(dist_M_`v') refmeans compute
```

Maybe somebody could improve my logic here.

Comment: As already pointed out, the loop over `1/9000` would by itself create 9000 new variables. There is precisely no built-in limitation to the values that `ind_id` has in practice. The easiest short-cut is to map your industry identifiers to a variable with 9 distinct values 1 to 9 using `egen, group()`. See http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-group-identifiers/index.html I understand almost nothing else in your question as I don't ever do this kind of calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Too long to fit into the space for a comment:

The problem report is in its entirety that the code is "wrong". What does that mean to anyone who can't try this out on your data (which isn't accessible)? Unless you make sample data available, meaning a complete dataset of modest size, and rewrite the problem consistently with its terms, I can't see that your problem will make much sense to anyone else.

The difficulty is compounded in this case by the fact that the number of experienced Stata programmers who also use this user-written package is going to be very small indeed. Note that your previous thread has received no answers, probably for similar reasons.

So far, so negative.

But I can say that your opening double loop will create **72000 new variables**, even if most of them are all missing values. Somehow you know that you have 9 industries, so why you are looping over `1/9000`? In different places you say that you want

72 new variables

72 * 7 new variables

These may be consistent somehow, but I don't see how.

The second code block isn't complete.

Comment: Not to mention that `mahascore` iteself is going to create an additional 576 variables if each of the 72 varlists contains 8 variables as in OP's example. Can't imagine this is going to run very smoothly with ~73,000 variables. I'm curious what flavor of Stata OP is using to allow more than 32767 variables.

Comment: @ander2ed `mahascore`  produces only 1 distance over all attributes (7 variables). So I would get 72 variables, which I could (in the theory) sum up to one variable, since 72 variables would contain values only for specific year-industry combination.

Comment: @Nick Cox Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I do not know, how to improve my code and totally understand that the question is badly written. I will try to improve it using your comments. I hope it will help.